# Como verificar a versao do .net core e desinstalar e reinstalar uma outra

Tags: c#

Preciso instalar a versao do .net core 2.0. Preciso saber qual a versao instalada e desinstalar para instalar essa. Como faco isso?

Comment: Use o CLI. Rode o comando `dotnet --version`. Não precisa desinstalar pra atualizar, é só instalar a nova que as duas convivem em harmonia.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore1x você pode usar via linha de comando (CMD por exemplo)

Se for a versão 1.x os argumentos suportados são:

```
dotnet [command] [arguments] [--additionalprobingpath] [-d|--diagnostics] [--fx-version]
    [-h|--help] [--info] [-v|--verbosity] [--version]
```

Versão 2.x:

```
dotnet [command] [arguments] [--additional-deps] [--additionalprobingpath] [-d|--diagnostics]
    [--fx-version] [-h|--help] [--info] [--roll-forward-on-no-candidate-fx] [-v|--verbosity] [--version]
```

Então creio que sendo versão 1.x ou 2.x pode-se usar o comando:

```
dotnet --version
```

Ou:

```
dotnet --info
```

---

### Lista de comandos da versão 1.x

- `--additionalprobingpath <PATH>`

  Caminho que contém a política de investigação e os assemblies a serem investigados.
- `-d` ou `--diagnostics`

  Habilita a saída de diagnóstico.
- `--fx-version <VERSION>`

  A versão do tempo de execução do .NET Core instalado a ser usada para executar o aplicativo.
- `-h` ou `--help`

  Imprime uma ajuda breve para o comando. Se estiver com dotnet, também imprimirá uma lista de comandos disponíveis.
- `--info`

  Imprime informações detalhadas sobre as ferramentas e o ambiente da CLI, como o sistema operacional atual, SHA de confirmação para a versão e outras informações.
- `-v` ou `--verbose`

  Habilita a saída detalhada.
- `--version`

  Imprime a versão do SDK do .NET Core em uso.

### Lista de comandos da versão 2.x

- `--additional-deps <PATH>`

  Caminho para o arquivo `deps.json` adicional.
- `--additionalprobingpath <PATH>`

  Caminho que contém a política de investigação e os assemblies a serem investigados.
- `-d` ou `--diagnostics`

  Habilita a saída de diagnóstico.
- `--fx-version <VERSION>`

  A versão do tempo de execução do .NET Core instalado a ser usada para executar o aplicativo.
- `-h` ou `--help`

  Imprime uma ajuda breve para o comando. Se estiver com dotnet, também imprimirá uma lista de comandos disponíveis.
- `--info`

  Imprime informações detalhadas sobre as ferramentas e o ambiente da CLI, como o sistema operacional atual, SHA de confirmação para a versão e outras informações.
- `--roll-forward-on-no-candidate-fx`

  Efetua roll forward em nenhuma estrutura compartilhada candidata.
- `-v` ou `--verbose`

  Habilita a saída detalhada.
- `--version`

  Imprime a versão do SDK do .NET Core em uso.